# How can I put drop downs inside a text

Tags: javascript, laravel, append, dropdown

Can anyone help me with this problem that I have.. thank you for everyone that tries to help me, so this is the text that comes from database
I am #OPTION and I am #OPTION years old. and I have the drop down that I can show with the append, but they appear only after the whole sentence I need the drop down to replace #OPTION  this is my code for the drop down

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
$(" p").append('<div class="btn-group"><select type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" ><option value="volvo">{{$answer->text}}</option></select></div>');});

</script>
```

so the `p` holds my text `I am #OPTION and I am #OPTION years old.` and thats why the drop down appears in the end, I tried  `$(" #OPTION ").append(`.. something like this but doesnt work, can anyone please help me how to replace the dropdown with the #OPTION..
I need it to be like this:

```
 I am [appear drop-down]  and I am [appear drop-down] years old.
```

Comment: is this what you want? https://jsfiddle.net/8wm96xb2/1/

Answer (score 0):

Html:

```
<p>
    I am #OPTION and I am #OPTION years old.
</p>
```

Js:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var value = $('p').html();

    var valueWithDropdowns = value.replace(
        new RegExp('#OPTION', 'g'),
        '<div class="btn-group"><select type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" ><option value="volvo">{{$answer->text}}</option></select></div>'
    );

    $("p").html(valueWithDropdowns);
});
```

I used regular expression in replace function to replace all occurrences of #OPTION in given string.

If you want to use different dropdowns for each placeholder you need to use to different placeholders e.g #OPTION_1, #OPTION_2 and replace each one using string replace function.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way. Lots of hard coding, but easy to modify to create dynamically.

```js
const nameSelect = $('<select></select>');
const person1 = $('<option value="person1">Person 1</option>');
const person2 = $('<option value="person2">Person 2</option>');
nameSelect.append(person1);
nameSelect.append(person2);

const ageSelect = $('<select></select>');
const age1 = $('<option value="6">6</option>');
const age2 = $('<option value="25">25</option>');
ageSelect.append(age1);
ageSelect.append(age2);

$('#dropdowns').append('I am ');
$('#dropdowns').append(nameSelect);
$('#dropdowns').append(' and I am ');
$('#dropdowns').append(ageSelect);
$('#dropdowns').append(' years old.');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="dropdowns"></div>
```

#### EDIT (creating values dynamically):

```js
const defaultOption = optionType => (
  $(`<option disabled selected value> -- select ${optionType} -- </option>`)
);

const names = ['Sally', 'Bill', 'Charlotte', 'Stephanie', 'Harry', 'John', 'Julia', 'Albert'];
const nameSelect = $('<select></select>');
nameSelect.append(defaultOption('name'));
names.forEach(name => {
  const nameOption = $(`<option value=${name}>${name}</option>`);
  nameSelect.append(nameOption);
});

const ages = Array(100).fill(null).map((el, idx) => idx + 1);
const ageSelect = $('<select></select>');
ageSelect.append(defaultOption('age'));
ages.forEach(age => {
  const ageOption = $(`<option value=${age}>${age}</option>`);
  ageSelect.append(ageOption);
});

const sentence = ['I am ', nameSelect, ' and I am ', ageSelect, ' years old.'];
sentence.forEach(part => $('#dropdowns').append(part));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="dropdowns"></div>
```

Comment: thank you very much this is the result that I want, but how can I create the text dynamically, I have this idea to make an array and use explode, in the php part like this Array ( [0] => I[1] => am[2] => #OPTION [3]..  but I do not know how to  put the drop down exactly the third one or whatever the position od the #option is, hope you can understand me, I am new in coding, thank you very much.

Comment: I've edited my answer to be more like what you're describing I think... Hope it helps!