# for is taking the last item in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, for-loop

I have this code

```
<?php  $json = json_encode($question->varz); ?>

@section('script')
<script type="text/javascript">
const nameSelect = $('<select></select>');
const person1 = $(' @foreach($question->answers as $answer)@if($answer->drop_down_owner==0) <option value="person1"> {{$answer->text}}</option>  @endif @endforeach');
nameSelect.append(person1);
const ageSelect = $('<select></select>');
const age1 = $(' @foreach($question->answers as $answer)@if($answer->drop_down_owner==1) <option value="person1"> {{$answer->text}}</option>  @endif @endforeach');
ageSelect.append(age1);


var json = <?php echo $json; ?>;
const dropdown = [ nameSelect, ageSelect];

 for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++)
      {
         if(json[i] != "#KDPOPTION"){
            $('#dropdowns').append(json[i]);
         }else
         {
              $('#dropdowns').append($(dropdown[0]));

         }
      }

</script>
```

and the result is `IamandIam[appears the dropdown]yearsold`. I need the dropdown to appear to in two places like this

```
Iam[appears the dropdown]andIam[appears the dropdown]yearsold.
```

so if I do i<4 the dropdown appears to the first place, if i<7 or larger the drop down appears only to the last place.

Comment: An exact [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45913784/how-can-i-put-drop-downs-inside-a-text/45914012#45914012), but a different account?

Comment: yea I know  I am working with a friend and she asked that question, and  she is not allowed to ask for 5 days, so I am asking different question in the same code, if anyone can help me I would be thankful..